# Move the file position without fseek in C

Tags: c, file

How can I move the file position back x bytes in C?

I don't want to use `fseek()`, because I'm reading lines of the file with `open(fd, buf, buflength)`, not `fopen()`.

I'd very much like to avoid reading the entire file into memory.

What I want to do is basically:

1. Read X + A = Y bytes.
2. Do something with the first X bytes.
3. Move the file pointer backwards A bytes.
4. Read Y bytes from there.

I know how to do everything except step 3. Anyone know how?

Comment: `int lseek(int fd, int position, int startpoint)`

Comment: Since you're reading the same bytes twice, why not just remember what they were and read more if necessary?  Then you don't need the backward seek.

Comment: @Dmitri I'm implementing a crypto function, which uses 16 bytes at a time, but I also need to check for a MAC at the end (and I don't know how long the file will be). So it's a lot easier to use the first 16 bytes of every read, and when it gets to the end, I'll know because the return value of read will be less than the amount I asked it to read, so I can finalize the HMAC from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/functions/unixio.html you could use lseek:

```
int lseek(int fd, int position, int startpoint)
  include: <unistd.h>
  Sets the file position effective for the next read or write operation.
  fd = file descriptor as returned by open
  position = position within file:
    number of bytes between startpoint and the desired position, may be negative.
  startpoint = location in file that position is relative to, one of:
    SEEK_SET        Position is number of bytes from beginning of file
    SEEK_END        Position is number of bytes after end of file
    SEEK_CUR        Position is number of bytes after current position
  returns <0 for error,
    or resulting file position relative to beginning of file.

  Moving beyond the end of the file is permitted; the file is extended in length
  only if a write occurs beyond the current end of file. Moving before the
  beginning of a file is not permitted. A write operation after a move only
  overwrites the number of bytes actually written.
```

Comment: @Duck I Googled for lseek and that was the first result

Comment: I think that's Google's "personalization" algorithm coming into play.When I do the same search I'll get man7.org, the opengroup, GNU, unixhelp, etc.